# Fetching data from DB and not getting correct value in input fields

Tags: php

I have fetch the data from the database.  I have a 7 checkbox and 2 tag text in the front of the checkboxes. I have written the logic for the checkbox that check the those checkbox which is in the database but in the text fields data is serving wrong i know the problem that $j is going wrong. Can you tell me what check should i write to get correct value of the text from checkbox according to the checkbox. I have Given the pic it will easy to understand.

PICTURE(see in the array according to weekname, i am not able to get the values of the texbox)->[HERE IS THE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipqnx.jpg)

**Now lets see the Code:**

```
 <?php
            $details=new User();

            $row=$details->Display('date',$ids);   
            $weeknames=array(1=>'Monday',2=>'Tuesday',3=>'Wednesday',4=>'Thursday',5=>'Friday',6=>'Saturday',7=>'Sunday');

            for($i=0;$i<count($row); $i++)
          {
           $arr[]= $row[$i]['name'];
           $start[]= $row[$i]['starttime'];
           $end[]= $row[$i]['endtime'];
           $id[]=$row[$i]['id'];
          }
          print_r($row);
         $j=0;
            foreach($weeknames as $key=>$value)
            {  
                // echo $j;
                ?>
              <br/>  <input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="mycheck" value="<?php echo $value ?>"  <?php if(in_array($value,$arr)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> /><?php echo $value ?> Start<input type="text"  userid="<?php  echo $ids; ?>" id="start<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php  if(in_array($value,$arr)) { echo $start[$j];  } ?>"  />End<input type="text" id="end<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php  if(in_array($value,$arr)) { echo $end[$j]; $j++;  }  ?>" /> <br />
                <?php 
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Anyone is here to help

Comment: I cant see any wrong data in the picture you have uploaded

Comment: @mehdijalilvand see in array What is in the keys...Like  checked checkbox have its own starttime and endtime

Comment: You're not incrementing `$j` for a start so it keeps the `0` value, also the object doesn't have values for Thursday, Friday and Saturday, thats why they are empty.

Comment: @akaBase Because it is not have data in database thats why it is not incrementing. Here is problem in array Monday is in 0 , and Tuesday 1, and Sunday in 3, and Wednesday is in 4 but i want to wednesday in  wednesday and sunday in sunday

Comment: Anyone is here  to help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should do what you are attempting to do but when making it I noticed a few things you should be aware of.

You use `mycheck` as the name for all checkboxes, you will want them to be unique if you need to know which is which and if not why set it at all.

Secondly `userid` is not a valid HTML attribute, if you wish to have it available use `data-userid` the `data-` then a name is a valid attribute.

```
$data = [
    ["id"=>1, "name"=>"Monday", "starttime"=>"12:12 PM", "endtime"=> "12:34 PM", "userid"=> ""],
    ["id"=>2, "name"=>"Tuesday", "starttime"=>"4:20 AM", "endtime"=>"11:00 AM", "userid"=> ""],
    ["id"=>3, "name"=>"Wednesday", "starttime"=>"2:22 AM", "endtime"=> "6:00 AM", "userid"=> ""],
    ["id"=>4, "name"=>"Sunday", "starttime"=>"3:12 PM", "endtime"=> "7:22 PM", "userid"=> ""]
];

$days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];

for($x = 0; $x < count($days); $x++){

    $day = $days[$x];
    $row = getRow($day, $data);

    if($row != null)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox'  id='{$day}' name='this-should-be-unique-{$x}' checked='checked'/> {$day} Start <input type='text' value='{$row['starttime']}'/> End <input type='text' value='{$row['endtime']}'/><br/> ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox'  id='{$day}' name='this-should-be-unique-{$x}' /> {$day} Start <input type='text' value=''/> End <input type='text' value=''/><br/> ";
    }
}

function getRow($day, $data){
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++){
        if($data[$x]["name"] == $day){
            return $data[$x];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: userid attribute is using in jquery thats why i am using it and i didnt find any problem, tell if this is wrong.  The checkbox  you have written is it dynamic and if fetch from the database does it work. As i see you have checked all the checkboxes  but i want to select only those who is in db. CAN YOU EXPLAIN LITTLE BIT MORE

Comment: using `userid` as an attribute is wrong, you should user `data-userid` and then from your jquery reference it with `$("#the-id-you-chose").data("userid")`, it is dynamic, the `$data` is just your `$arr` but hardcode for the example. and no not all checkboxes will be checked, they are only checked if data for that day is found, thats what the `null` check is.

Comment: what should i do while inserting. Like there is moday already and it is checked but i want to add one more then what will be the query. Can there is where clause in insert query

Comment: I do not understand your question, but it does seem out of scope for this question. If it is I suggest asking another question with the details of this new question.

Comment: Yes this new question i want to just know if i add one more checkbox i want to insert only that new checked checkbox older one should not have dual entry on the insertation.